# Custom deserialization for JSON

Tags: c#, json, asp.net-web-api

I have a model for my web api controller like this:

```
    public class CompanyDetailedModel 
    {
        public IList<PhoneContactModel> Phones { get; set; }
    }
```

When in the request I receive json like

```
{ "Phones": [] }
```

it is ok - my internal collection Phones is null. But when I recieve

```
{ "Phones": [{}] }
```

my Phones collection has one empty object `default(PhoneContactModel)`.

Is it posible to avoid this behavior and on `[{}]` have null?

Comment: It sounds like you want to change the behavior of the JsonSerializer Web Api is using... you can take a look at http://www.asp.net/web-api/overview/formats-and-model-binding/json-and-xml-serialization... Also may I ask why you cant just do a quick check that the object is null?

Comment: Because on { "Phones": [{}] } my model is not a null and in my controller's action I have model with one default initialized object. So I have to save it in my Db, but i don`t want to do it, so I need for now check my collection on default initialized objects and cut it off. So on { "Phones": [{}] } I want to my model be null

Comment: As far as I see you have two options... 1) implement and roll your own JSON serializer which is probably not a good idea. 2) do a check on your Controller that the CompanyDetailedModel.Phones collection has only one null value in it then its a request with { "Phones": [{}] } and dont save to DB ...